# Odd runtime error in C?

Tags: c

For some reason i keep getting an odd runtime error when i run this program. It compiles fine, and most of the program works.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    printf("This program will show you the scores of the basketball games for 1 season.\n");
    printf("What is the name of the basketball league? ");
    string league = GetLine();
    printf("How may games were played by the group? ");
    int gamesplayed = GetInteger();
    string teams[3];
    int wonGames[3];
    int a, b, c;
    for (a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    {
        printf("What is team %d's name? ", a+1);
        teams[a] = GetLine(); 
    }
    for (b = 0; b < 4; b++)
    {
        printf("How many times did team %s win? ", teams[b]);
        wonGames[b] = GetInteger();

    }

    printf("\n\n ----===[%s]===----\n", league);
    printf("Team Name | Games Played | Games Won | Percentage");
    for(c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        double percent = 100 * (wonGames[c]/gamesplayed);
        printf("| %s | %d | %d | %lf |", teams[c], gamesplayed, wonGames[c], percent);
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be with printing `teams[3]` in the last for loop. No matter what i do it crashes after it prints  `printf("Team Name | Games Played | Games Won | Percentage");`

The library `GetInteger()` and `GetLine()` are the two functions i use to get input, its from the simpio.h library. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: If array indexing starts at 0 then shouldnt teams[3] have four elements? (0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: The array `teams` has only three entries, so there is no `teams[3]`. The same goes for `wonGames`.

Comment: I would suggest you #define numEntries (4) then change your array definitions to use numEntries and change your for statement(s) to use numEntries

Comment: assuming that GetLine() and GetInteger() are your personal functions, I expect GetLine() to return a pointer to a malloc'd memory allocation, where the allocated memory contains the line or the integer. Therefore, "string league" should be (assuming that 'string' is a valid type) "string *league"

Comment: this line: double percent = 100 * (wonGames[c]/gamesplayed); is using an integer divide, an integer 100 and eventually converted to double.  however the divide operation will be an integer divide, and won games will be less than gamesplayed, so the result of the divide would always be 0.  suggest double percent = 100.0 * ((double)wonGames[c]/(double)gamesplayed); or even better: double percent = (100.0 * (wonGames[c])/gamesplayed);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string teams[3];
for (a = 0; a < 4; a++)
{
    printf("What is team %d's name? ", a+1);
    teams[a] = GetLine(); 
}
```

You are going out of bounds, since `teams` has size 3 and `a` will eventually get the value 3.

Indexing starts from 0 to size of array - 1. So change 4 with 3, or increase the size by one.

Do the same for `wonGames`.

Similarly, the loop with the counter `c` should be modified too (if the size of the array is not increased).

---

Answer for the edit.

Q: If array indexing starts at 0 then shouldnt teams[3] have for elements? (0, 1, 2, 3)

A: **NO**. The array has size 3, thus it can hold 3 elements, the first is in the 0th cell, the second in the 1st cell and the third in the 2nd cell.

Answer (score 2):

Your array "teams" has three elements. Your printing loop accesses four elements.